# Which is broken: the DICOM or the converter?

Tags: dicom

I'm trying to convert a 4D DICOM image (x,y,z,time) to a different file format. Something goes wrong, because the output image has lost the time dimension.

I'm trying to decide whether:

- the DICOM series is broken -- it's possible that a 3rd party, who anonymized data, removed critical information from the header; or
- the conversion code is incomplete -- it simply can't handle this flavour of DICOM

The answer to this will determine whether I have to fix the DICOM, or fix the converter.

I've tried diving into the [DICOM standard](http://medical.nema.org/Dicom/2011/11_06pu.pdf), to understand what specific header values mean, but I don't find this document helpful; it gives a mere word or two for each header field. I see fields in my data that look suspicious, but I don't know if it's actually wrong, or if I don't understand what it's supposed to be telling me.

I can think of several ways to answer my problem:

1. Are there any tools out there that can confidently classify a DICOM series as either valid or invalid?
2. Is there a document which describes precisely what each DICOM header value is *supposed* to contain?
3. Is there a better approach to figuring out which is broken -- the image, or the converter?

Comment: 1. Osirix's Dicom validator which is based on DCLunie's Dicom validator 2. For a given SOP class the DICOM standard specifies what tags are mandatory/conditional and optional. See PS 3.3. 3. You could write your own converter or just interrogate the file using python, matlab, java etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at the right document, you should be looking at [PS 3.3 - current](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/PS3.3.html). For example:

- [A.4.3 MR Image IOD Module Table](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.4.3.html)

Or as someone mentioned in the comments use [dciodvfy](http://www.dclunie.com/dicom3tools/dciodvfy.html) from [dicom3tools](http://www.dclunie.com/dicom3tools.html) package.